# FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams callback handler never gets called

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, callback, handler

I'm using FBDialogs to share on Facebook.

The facebook sharing works correctly, but the handler never gets called (I put a breakpoint on the first line)

My SDK is installed through CocoaPods

```
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK',         '3.9.0'
```

here's the code, pretty much the example on facebook dev page. I'm testing on an IPod with ios7.

```
// If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {
    // Present the share dialog

    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:params
                              clientState:nil
                                    handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                        //never gets here
                                        if(error) {
                                            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"O comparilhando não foi bem sucedido. %@",error.description]
                                                                                           delegate:nil
                                                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                            [alert show];

                                        } else {
                                            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sucesso"
                                                                                            message:@"O compartilhando foi bem sucedido"
                                                                                           delegate:nil
                                                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                            [alert show];

                                        }}];
```

**SOLUTION**:

My boss figured it out in the end.
I was missing this method in my AppDelegate. Without it, facebook couldn't pass data back to my app

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:        (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

BOOL urlWasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                              fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                                  // incoming link processing goes here
                                }];

    return urlWasHandled;
}
```

Comment: Did you check if the FaceBook session is open?

Comment: How can i check that? What exactly is Facebook session?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {


    if ([[[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:0]isEqualToString:@"your FB ID"]) {

        return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];

    }
```

May be this help you.